# parallelize a simple sql query in R

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc, snow, doparallel

I am executing a simple SQL query via R

```
 library(RODBC)
 ConnectODBC1 = odbcConnect("Netezza1", uid ="King", believeNRows= FALSE)
 OrderData = sqlQuery(ConnectODBC1 , paste("select * from ADMIN. PhysicianOrder"))
```

This is taking forever. Sometimes I get an error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 250.0 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In odbcFetchRows(channel, max= max, buffersize = buffersize, nullstring = nullstring, :
Reached total allocation of 1638Mb : see help(memory.size)
```

I am assuming executing the sql query in parallel will solve this problem, I am wondering if anybody can give me some pointers if they faced similar issues.

Comment: That's not a very big memory request in the grand scheme of things and you don't seem to have very much RAM. Time for a hardware investment. (I don't see how parallelization is relevant here.)

Comment: @BondedDust I am executing this no a 4 core CPU with 16gb RAM and my Windows Task Manager shows 98% Physical Memory used

Comment: You have too much other junk in your system ... someplace, possibly not in R but in other Windows apps. Windows is not particularly good at memory management.

Comment: @BondedDust I am still curious to know how I can prallelize the query

Comment: The number of SO hits for `[r] sql parallel` is 24;  number for `[r] Netezza parallel` is zero.

Comment: @BondedDust :-) you got me big time man, I have no idea what that means

Comment: Searching on StackOverflow produces no questions or answers where the three search terms `[r] Netezza parallel` appear together. I suggest broadening your search for advice regarding Netezza's parallelization capacities. I still think the error messages shows you are not using your memory resources well.